# Do cats learn how to hunt from their mothers?

Tags: cats, hunting

Do cats learn how to hunt from their mothers? Do orphaned cats not know how to hunt as well or at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes kittens learn this from their mothers,But they will learn from experience too.

The mother will bring dead prey to her kittens first and often throw it around a little in front of her kittens,this is to get the kittens interrested so they start to play with it.

Later the mother will bring live prey to her kittens this is so they can learn how to do the kill.

The stalking part of the hunt is more instinct and experience so the kittens do not learn this from their mother,You can see kittens learning this from playing with each other.

Orphaned kittens do learn how to hunt but it will often take more time before they can do this sucsessfully,A large part of how kittens learn how to hunt is by playing with their siblings.

As a side note when a cat brings you prey it is not a gift it is more a reminder that you need to learn how to hunt so you can feed yourself and survive(my cat brings prey into my house not to give it to me but to eat it in peace from other cats)she knows i can hunt i give her raw meat as a treat sometimes.